# How to bulk insert rows into realm database from web (JSON) in Xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, realm

This is my very first attempt to work with Xamarin studio with Realm (to make app for both iOS and Android) and I am stuck at this situation since last 24 hours.

My online database-table has 30,000 rows. Earlier when I used to work in Android studio, I used to import those rows in app's 1st run with the help of JSON, GSON and insert into SQLite db.

But I am unable to do so in Realm & Xamarin. I know, I have not provided any code snippet (my effort), but honestly even after searching a lot about this, I couldn't find how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already answered that in the [Github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/881#issuecomment-255773311), but in case someone else stumbles across it, the best way to do that without blocking the UI thread, is to use the [`Realm.WriteAsync`](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/api/class_realms_1_1_realm.html#a619591195b606a70d1a3aed5c6195887) API. Basically, you'll do something like:

```
var items = await service.GetAllItems();
// I assume items are already deserialized RealmObject-s
var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
await realm.WriteAsync(r =>
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        r.Manage(item);
    }
}
/* Data is loaded, show message or process it in other ways */
```

One thing to note is that within the `WriteAsync` lambda, we're using the `r` instance and not the original `realm` one. The reason is that because realms are not thread safe and the asynchronous write will happen on another thread, so it implicitly creates another instance and passes it as an argument of the action parameter.